# The technology used for stack

Tags: discussion, stackoverflow

The user interface of stack family websites is really cute. What technology/ frame-work is it based on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network) has all the gory details

Comment: It's best to just link to the meta.so site as that post is updated over time. Copying means this one will get out of date over time and probably not be updated ... now this reminds me i need to update that post